# ValueError with ReLU function in python

Tags: python, relu

I declared ReLU function like this:

```
def relu(x):
    return (x if x > 0 else 0)
```

and an ValueError has occured and its traceback message is

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

But if I change ReLU function with numpy, it works:

```
def relu_np(x):
    return np.maximum(0, x)
```

Why this function(`relu(x)`) doesn't work? I cannot understand it...

================================

Used code:

```
>>> x = np.arange(-5.0, 5.0, 0.1)
>>> y = relu(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "filename", line, in relu
    return (x if x > 0 else 0)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Where and how are you calling this function?

Comment: I used numpy.arange, and will add a code on this question right now

Comment: your ternary operation `(x if x > 0 else 0)` is trying to do an if, else based on `x>0` which expects a single value and not an array. This is the reason for the error. However, for numpy you are using a vectorized function `np.maximum` which appies independently to each element of the array. Check details in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that `x > 0` is an array of booleans, a mask if you like:

```
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True])
```

So it does not make sense to do `if x>0`, since x contains several elements, which can be `True` or `False`. This is the source of your error.

Your second implementation of numpy is good ! Another implementation (maybe more clear?) might be:

```
def relu(x):
  return x * (x > 0)
```

In this implementation, we do an elementwise multiplication of x, which is a range of values along the x axis, by 0 if the element of x is below 0, and 1 if the element is above.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR;** Your first function is not using vectorized methods which means it expects a single float/int value as input, while your second function takes advantage of Numpy's vectorization.

### Vectorization in NumPy

Your second function uses numpy functions which are vectorized and run on each individual element of the array.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(-5.0, 5.0, 0.5)

def relu_np(x):
    return np.maximum(0, x)

relu_np(arr)

# array([0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.5, 1. ,
#        1.5, 2. , 2.5, 3. , 3.5, 4. , 4.5])
```

Your second function however uses a ternary operator `(x if x > 0 else 0)` which expects a single value input and outputs a single value. This is why when you pass a single element, it would work, but on passing an array it fails to run the function on each element independently.

```
def relu(x):
    return (x if x > 0 else 0)

relu(-8)

## 0
```

> `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`
>
> Note: The reason for this error is due to the ternary operator you are using `(x if x > 0 else 0)`. The condition `x>0` can only take the value `True` or `False` for a given integer/float value. However, when you pass an array, you will need to use something like `any()` or `all()` to aggregate that list of boolean values to a single one, before you can apply your if, else clause.

### Solutions -

There are a few ways you can make this work -

##### 1. Using np.vectorize (not recommended, lower performance than pure numpy approach)

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(-5.0, 5.0, 0.5)

def relu(x):
    return (x if x > 0.0 else 0.0)

relu_vec = np.vectorize(relu)
relu_vec(arr)

# array([0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.5, 1. ,
#        1.5, 2. , 2.5, 3. , 3.5, 4. , 4.5])
```

##### 2. Iteration over the array with list comprehension

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(-5.0, 5.0, 0.5)

def relu(x):
    return (x if x > 0 else 0)

arr = np.array(arr)

np.array([relu(i) for i in arr])

# array([0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.5, 1. ,
#        1.5, 2. , 2.5, 3. , 3.5, 4. , 4.5])
```

Comment: It seems to me that your solution 2 would be the one with lowest performance.  In fact, here is what i get : pure numpy : 13.9 microseconds, vectorise : 1.5 ms, iteration : 5.2 ms (need a fairly large array to illustrate the fact that iteration is slower than the vectorized form)

Comment: Apologies but I wasn't comparing the 2 approaches, just added the last approach later. The low performance is w.r.t the pure numpy approach vs vectorized approach. Let me edit that to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: please someone correct me if I'm wrong, I'm not 100% sure about how numpy does things.

Your function `relu` expects a single numerical value and compares it to 0 and returns whatever is larger. `x if x > 0 else 0` would be equal to `max(x, 0)` where `max` is a builtin Python function.

`relu_np` on the other hand uses the numpy function `maximum` which accepts 2 numbers **or** arrays **or** iterables. That means you can pass your numpy array `x` and it applies the maximum function to every single item automatically. I believe this is called 'vectorized'.

To make the `relu` function you have work the way it is, you need to call it differently. You'd have to manually apply your function to every element. You could do something like `y = np.array(list(map(relu, x)))`.